# ggplot2 economics dataset not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been teaching a few friends some basic R, and was doing some plots with the economics data from ggplot2.  Everyone has a windows laptop except one guy who has a MacBook...and he is the only one experiencing this error.

He has installed and library'd the ggplot2 package with no issues, but when he runs

```
data("economics")
```

He gets

```
Warning message:
In data("economics") : data set ‘economics’ not found
```

I wouldn't think that Mac vs PC would have anything to do with it and that it's purely coincidental...but I don't really know how to rectify this.

Comment: Can you show the exact output of `sessionInfo()` before you run `data("economics")`? It sounds like the `ggplot2` library did not load. Verify that it is in the `sessionInfo()` output. Also try `data("economics", package="ggplot2")`

Comment: I will ask him to do that and send me the output...but ggplot2 is definitely loaded.  Prior to this we were using the diamonds data set to make scatter, box, and violin plots and that all worked fine.

Comment: The sessionInfo will also output version numbers for all packages loaded, that might be relevant as well. But something just doesn't seem right. Is this user using Rmarkdown or something rather than the interactive R console?

Comment: Nope, just the console in RStudio...it's weird.  I've never seen it before

Comment: we really need to know `packageVersion("ggplot2")` ...

Comment: `data("economics", package="ggplot2")` worked, which makes me think that even through they SAID they had run `library(ggplot2)` they might not have....

Answer (score 0):

You can access a lazy data set without calling `library('package')`:

```
economics <- ggplot2::economics
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?